# Security rules for posting to a user's subdirectory in Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

The following are my Firebase security rules:

security-rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine when my path ends with the `users` directory. As in:

```
https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/users/my-user-id.json
```

But when I try to post directly to a subdirectory, as follows:

```
https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/users/my-user-id/settings.json
```

it doesn't work.

### Question

> **What do I need to do to the security-rules.json file (or anything else) to be able to write directly to a user's subdirectory?**

Edit:

Someone suggested, "just extend your rule to include settings." So I tried this:

security-rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      },
      "settings": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
9:30: Unknown variable '$uid'.
10:31: Unknown variable '$uid'.
```

Comment: `curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/users/my-user-id.json` works. `curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/users/my-user-id/settings.json` doesn't work.

Comment: just extend your rule to include settings

Comment: @PascalGula: Could you please show a quick example as an answer?

Comment: The `Unknown variable '$uid'.` error message you're getting is because you did something different than proposed. @PascalGula nested `settings` *inside* the `$uid` rule, you put it outside. I don't think his approach will help, but the syntax error will disappear if you correctly use his rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen well, why should it fails? https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables depends

Comment: @Mowzer it doesn't work is almost always a bad thing to say here. What are you expecting to happen and what happenes exactly? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Good point @AndréKool. Mowzer: when you run the read/write operation in the Simulator in your Firebase's dashboard, it'll tell you why the operation failed. If that doesn't explain it, can you add it to your question? That should give us something more to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in the simulator:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        "settings": {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Once a user has read or write permission on a certain level, it cannot be taken away on a lower level. See [Rules Cascade in the Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade). Since the user already has access on the` $uid` level, adding the same rule on `settings` under it won't change anything.

Comment: understood, will modify it accordingly by separating the rules

Comment: This works in the simulator so I accepted and upvoted because I love to give rep to helpful people. However, I still have the problem in real life (outside the simulator) so I'm working on it and might post a follow up question soon.

Comment: oki doki, thanks, I'll follow up since I am also interested by the topic! :)

Comment: Based on a comment I just read there, it looks like I still have more work to do to fully explain the question. But I just wanted to give you a heads up that [here's the updated question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34301172/1640892) and more explanation will follow.

Comment: Apparently, that wasn't such a good attempt. [I have rewritten the question again here in a separate post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34331388/1640892). There is a **lot of detail** but it reads fast. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

After further testing, I found the security rules contained in the OP also work in the simulator:

security-rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no need to add additional rules for writing deeper into the node tree. The highest level permissions are sufficient.

Aside: My problem appears to be something other than the security rules I'm using. I must do more research, experimentation and testing.