# Firebase simulator does not match real-world results

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

For the purposes of convenience in reading this question, refer to the following URLs as follows:

URL definitions:

```
url1 = 'https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/users/user-id/settings';
url2 = url1 + '.json';
```

I have tested two different security scenarios — with security and without security. Both in the Firebase simulator and in real life. As follows.

without-security.json:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

with-security.json:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        "settings": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, consider the different results from the Firebase simulator vs. real life testing.

Test results:

```
      Security Simulator                         Real life
      -------- ---------                         ---------
url1  No       (untested)                        Fails (without error message)
url2  No       (untested)                        Success!
url1  Yes      Success!                          Fails (without error message)
url2  Yes      Invalid path. Simulation aborted. POST <url2> 401 (Unauthorized)
```

## Questions

- What could be causing this discrepancy in test results vs. real life?
- What should I try in order to get real life scenario to work `with-security.json` rules in place?

Comment: This is still the same problem as your previous question. Post the exact operation you do. If it's a write, post the URL and the JSON you put in the simulator **and** the code that you use. Without those, we're guessing as to what you're doing. Also note that the simulator gives an explanation of how it comes to the result it comes to. Post that output.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thank you for your helpful writing suggestions. Inspired by this comment, [I have rewritten this question in a separate post here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34331388/1640892). There is a **lot of detail** but it reads fast. Thanks, again.

Comment: Don't open a new question for the same problem. By now that's the third question you posted on it, and it's still difficult to figure out. To be honest: this question was closer, but without seeing a **minimal** snippet of the write operation that fails (either the URL and JSON you put in the emulator or the code), it is impossible to see what's going on. I'm trying to dig it up from your latest question, but you really should've just added that information here.

Answer (score 0):

[@FrankvanPuffelen answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338733/1640892):

> Both of your problems are caused by the fact that you're using two different ways of accessing Firebase: the JavaScript SDK and the REST API. While these two methods can be used together, you will have to ensure you provide the information that is needed. In general you will have an easier experience if you stick to using one way of accessing Firebase from a single client.